# erasing one vector of a 2d vector c++ by judging an element of that vector

Tags: c++, vector

```
vector< vector<int> > 2d_vector;
```

here 2d_vector is a n*3 vector where n indicates the element of it, e.g.
2d_vector = { {0,0,2}, {0,0,1}, {0,0,0}, {0,0,-1} }

I was trying to erase elements of this 2d_vector that fit "2d_vector[i][2] == -1", where i is from 0 to n.
My code is as follows:

```
vector< vector<int> >::iterator it = 2d_vector.begin();
    for( ;it<2d_vector.end();it+=3){
        if(**(it+2) == -1){         
            it = staticBlocks.erase(it); 
        }
    }
```

But it does not work.
How should I do?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: * n indicates the total number of elements of this 2d_vector.

Comment: Surely your code cannot compile.  `2d_vector` is not a valid name for an identifier.  Use `vector_2d` instead.

Comment: There is an [MCve] needed.

Comment: `2d_vector` here is just for better understanding, I used another proper name in my real program. Sorry for the misleading.

Answer (score 0):

Let's break down `**(it+2)`. `it+2` refers to the second `vector` after the one referenced by `it`. `*(it+2)` dereferences the iterator and gets the second `vector` after the one referenced by `it`. This is a `vector`, not a pointer or an iterator. It cannot be dereferenced, so `**(it+2)` is doomed. However, `(*(it+2))[0]` Should do what you appear to want.

This assumes `it+2` is within range.

Comment: I tried this way, the program aborts from the for loop.

Comment: Where and why does it abort? If you do not know, your development environment's debugger may help.

Comment: It aborts from one of the erase() operation inside the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You meant that kind of thing? :

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> vec;
    for (std::vector<std::vector<int>>::iterator it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); ++it) {
    if (it->at(2) == -1){
        vec.erase(it);
        --it; // This may fix it, if a vector gets deleted, the rest of the list goes one step towards the beggining of it and the next vector will be skipped
    }
}
```

It fits to this

> erase elements of this 2d_vector that fit "2d_vector[i][2] == -1",

Comment: I tried this way but the program aborts from the for loop.

Comment: Where? How? Edit your answer, i don't understand why

Comment: I think i found out, try with that

Comment: It still aborts from one of the erase operation inside the for loop, maybe still issues about the addresses.

Comment: What do you mean with "abort" exactly?

Comment: **[1]    4295 abort      ./a.out**

Comment: This is the last line when I run a.out